# resizing window inputs box collapse to left side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in this project (only javascript (jquery) ,css and HTML5) in trying to keep the inputs in the right side of the receptive description such as the follow image show[image]

But instead, when i resize, the input boxes collapse to the left side of the description, such as the photo show.[image]

So my question is how can i solve this problem, keeping my inputs always at the right side, even when i resize. i will paste some code, related to those divs

```css
.leftPane {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  resize: both;
}

.rightPane {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  resize: both;
}

@media (max-height: 860px) {
  .leftPane {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .rightPane {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

#steps {
  width: 600px;
  /*height:320px;*/
}

.step {
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
  /*height:320px;*/
  height: inherit;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 id="contentTitle">ETAP Ley configurator</h1>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="steps" class="steps">
      <form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="" method="post">
        <!-- Project Definitions -->
        <fieldset class="step">
          <legend id="stepTitle_0">Project Definition</legend>
          <div id="stepDesc_0" class="txtbox">
            Create light lines with Ley, the modular lighting system. Draw your own personalized configuration here. Choose short or long lines, straight or angled, with or without uplight, suspended, ceiling mounted or wall mounted… The possibilities are endless!
            <br><br>
            <!-- Please fill in the projet data -->
            Please fill in the project information
          </div>
          <!--  Left Pane -->
          <div class="rightPane" id="Pane">
            <p style="padding:5px 0"><label id="projLabel">Project</label></p>
            <p>
              <label for="pname" id="pname_lbl">Name</label>
              <input id="pname" name="pname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="proom" id="proom_lbl">Room</label>
              <input id="proom" name="proom" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Main Hall" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="paddr" id="paddr_lbl">Address</label>
              <input id="paddr" name="paddr" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="date" id="date_lbl">Date</label>
              <input id="date" name="date" type="text" disabled/>
            </p>
          </div>
          <!--  Right Pane -->
          <div class="leftPane" id="Pane">

            <p><label id="contactLabel">Contact</label></p>
            <p>
              <label for="cname" id="cname_lbl">Name</label>
              <input id="cname" name="cname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF maxlength="11" />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="email" id="email_lbl">E-mail</label>
              <input id="email" class="email" name="email" placeholder="e.g. mail@mail.com" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF onBlur="checkEmail(this.value)" />

            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="phone" id="phone_lbl">Phone</label>
              <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="e.g. +3233100211" type="number" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF/>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="caddr" id="caddr_lbl">Address</label>
              <input id="caddr" name="caddr" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="country" id="country_lbl">Country</label>
              <select id="country" name="country">
                <option value='blank' disabled selected value> </option>
                <option value='be' id="country_op0">Belgium</option>
                <option value='lu' id="country_op1">Luxembourg</option>
                <option value='fr' id="country_op2">France</option>
                <option value='de' id="country_op3">Germany</option>
                <option value='nl' id="country_op4">The Netherlands</option>
                <option value='pt' id="country_op5">Portugal</option>
                <option value='es' id="country_op6">Spain</option>
                <option value='se' id="country_op7">Sweden</option>
                <option value='other' id="country_op8">Other</option>
              </select>
            </p>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted your code to `display: flex;` you can achieve it with less code

**check the snippet:**

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.leftPane,.rightPane {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 id="contentTitle">ETAP Ley configurator</h1>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="steps" class="steps">
      <form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="" method="post">
        <!-- Project Definitions -->
        <fieldset class="step">
          <legend id="stepTitle_0">Project Definition</legend>
          <div id="stepDesc_0" class="txtbox">
            Create light lines with Ley, the modular lighting system. Draw your own personalized configuration here. Choose short or long lines, straight or angled, with or without uplight, suspended, ceiling mounted or wall mounted… The possibilities are endless!
            <br><br>
            <!-- Please fill in the projet data -->
            Please fill in the project information
          </div>
          <!--  Left Pane -->
          <div class="content">
            <div class="rightPane" id="Pane">
              <p style="padding:5px 0"><label id="projLabel">Project</label></p>
              <p>
                <label for="pname" id="pname_lbl">Name</label>
                <input id="pname" name="pname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
              </p>
              <p>
                <label for="proom" id="proom_lbl">Room</label>
                <input id="proom" name="proom" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Main Hall" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
              </p>
              <p>
                <label for="paddr" id="paddr_lbl">Address</label>
                <input id="paddr" name="paddr" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
              </p>
              <p>
                <label for="date" id="date_lbl">Date</label>
                <input id="date" name="date" type="text" disabled/>
              </p>
            </div>
            <!--  Right Pane -->
            <div class="leftPane" id="Pane">

              <p><label id="contactLabel">Contact</label></p>
              <p>
                <label for="cname" id="cname_lbl">Name</label>
                <input id="cname" name="cname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF maxlength="11" />
              </p>
              <p>
                <label for="email" id="email_lbl">E-mail</label>
                <input id="email" class="email" name="email" placeholder="e.g. mail@mail.com" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF onBlur="checkEmail(this.value)" />

              </p>
              <p>
                <label for="phone" id="phone_lbl">Phone</label>
                <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="e.g. +3233100211" type="number" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF/>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label for="caddr" id="caddr_lbl">Address</label>
                <input id="caddr" name="caddr" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
              </p>
              <p>
                <label for="country" id="country_lbl">Country</label>
                <select id="country" name="country">
                  <option value='blank' disabled selected value> </option>
                  <option value='be' id="country_op0">Belgium</option>
                  <option value='lu' id="country_op1">Luxembourg</option>
                  <option value='fr' id="country_op2">France</option>
                  <option value='de' id="country_op3">Germany</option>
                  <option value='nl' id="country_op4">The Netherlands</option>
                  <option value='pt' id="country_op5">Portugal</option>
                  <option value='es' id="country_op6">Spain</option>
                  <option value='se' id="country_op7">Sweden</option>
                  <option value='other' id="country_op8">Other</option>
                </select>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```